# Successfully uploaded image to Cloudinary from React Native does not return URL

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload image from React Native app to Cloudinary.
The image appears on Dashboard, but I don't get secure_url.

Here is my code:

```
  async uploadImage(photo: ImagePickerResponse, id: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>(async (resolve, reject) => {
      const uploadPreset = 'bbbbbb';
      const cloudName = 'aaaaa';

      const body = new FormData();
      const uri: string =
        Platform.OS === 'android' ? photo.uri : photo.uri.replace('file://', '');
      const type = photo.type;
      const name = `eMia${id}.jpeg`;
      const file = {uri, type, name};
      body.append('file', file);
      body.append('upload_preset', uploadPreset);
      body.append('cloud_name', cloudName);
      const url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/image/upload`;

      fetch(url, {method: 'POST', body})
        .then((res) => {
          // I don't have Body here so i don't have the image url :(
          console.log(res);
          res.json();
        })
        .then((json) => {
          console.log(json);
          const url = json.secure_url;
          console.log(url);
          resolve(url);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
```

Response:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

React Native app uploads photo to the Cloudinary server and get link to the photo.
File from Image Picker is uploaded to the Cloudinary for two steps. On the first step the photo is uploaded to the app server:

```
import {DBStorageInteractor} from '../interfaces';
import {BASE_URL} from '../../../config/constants';
import ImageResizer from 'react-native-image-resizer';
import {ImagePickerResponse} from 'react-native-image-picker';

    
  async uploadImage(photo: ImagePickerResponse, id: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise<string>(async (resolve, reject) => {
      if (!photo) {
        reject(Error('Photo is not presented'));
        return;
      }
      this.getBody(photo, id)
        .then((body) => {
          const headers = {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          };
          const options = {
            method: 'POST',
            body: body,
            headers: headers,
          };
          fetch(`${BASE_URL()}/api/images/upload`, options)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
              const secureUrl = response.secure_url;
              console.log('Uploaded successfully. Url=', secureUrl);
              resolve(secureUrl);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              const message = `Failed uploading. Error=${error}`;
              console.log(message);
              reject(Error(message));
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          reject(error);
        });
    });
  }

  getBody(photo: ImagePickerResponse, id: string): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (photo.fileSize < 100000) {
        resolve(
          JSON.stringify({
            img: photo.data,
            name: `eMia${id}.${this.getFileExtension(photo.uri)}`,
          })
        );
      } else {
        ImageResizer.createResizedImage(photo.uri, 400, 400, 'JPEG', 80)
          .then(({uri}) => {
            RNFS.readFile(uri, 'base64')
              .then((data) => {
                resolve(
                  JSON.stringify({
                    img: data,
                    name: `eMia${id}.${this.getFileExtension(photo.uri)}`,
                  })
                );
              })
              .catch((error) => {
                reject(error);
              });
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
          });
      }
    });
  }

  getFileExtension(filename) {
    return filename.slice((filename.lastIndexOf(".") - 1 >>> 0) + 2);
  }
```

Pic. 1. Client side of the app uploads photo from Image Picker to the server side and gets link to the photo.

On the second step server side (on NodeJS) handles request for two steps. It writes file image from the request to a temporary directory and then uploads it to the Cloudinary server:

```
const {Router} = require('express')
const router = Router()
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;
const fs = require('fs')
// /api/images/upload
router.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const file = req.body.img;
      const name = req.body.name;
      const path = `tmp/${name}`;
      // Write received fire in temporary folder
      fs.writeFile(path, file, 'base64', (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          throw err
        }
        // Upload file to the Cloudinary server
        cloudinary.uploader.upload(path)
          .then((results) => {
            res.status(200).json(results)
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            res.status(400).json(error)
          });
      })
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json(error)
    }
  }
)
```

Pic. 2. Handling request '/upload' on the NodeJS server.

Configure Cloudinary on the server side:

```
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary').v2;

require('dotenv').config();

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.cloud_name,
  api_key: process.env.api_key,
  api_secret: process.env.api_secret,
});
```

File .env (in root of the project) consists following parameters:

```
cloud_name=<Cloudinary cloud name>
api_key=<API key from the Cloudinary project settings>
api_secret=<API secret from the Cloudinary project settings>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you please try the following code:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class Upload extends React.Component {
  processFile = async e => {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var formdata = new FormData();

    formdata.append("file", file);
    formdata.append("cloud_name", "shirly");
    formdata.append("upload_preset", "my-preset");

    let res = await fetch(
      "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/emia/auto/upload",
      {
        method: "post",
        mode: "cors",
        body: formdata
      }
    );

    let json = await res.json();
    console.log(JSON.stringify(json.secure_url));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Upload</h3>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.processFile} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<Upload />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: Thanks fr answer. As i understand you suggest to use 'mode: "cors",' option. I tried it. The same result: Image on server but i don't get its url on response